# Create Basic Catalog System with Prolog

Tags: prolog

So we have an assignment to create a catalog system wherein we are supposed to add, edit, delete records of books in a system we created and compute for the total number of items recorded.

the information recorded or inputted should include the name of the author and the title of the book for example. Still cant wrap my head around how to do it and really need help. so far this code all I've got for now.

I wanted to know how exactly to do this task as i have no idea how to continue on this.

```
menu:- repeat,
    write('Online Public Catalog System'),nl,
    write('[1]Add Records'),nl,
    write('[2]Edit Records'),nl,
    write('[3]Delete Records'),nl,
    write('[4]Display and Calculate for books'),nl,
    write('[5]Exit'),nl,
    write('Choose from the select menu'),nl,
    read(Choice),Choice>0, Choice =<2,
    doit(Choice), Choice=2, !.
doit(1):-
    writeln('Input name of author:'),readln(M),
    writeln('Input title of Book:'),readln(C),
    record(book([C]),author([M])).
doit(2):-
    write('To edit an existing book, please enter the Title and Author: '),nl,
    read(T,A),
    update([T,A]|books).
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which of Sicstus or SWI Prolog is being used? Has both tags. You'll want to use retract and friends, see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=retract/1

Comment: @TA_intern i have no idea how to do it, how to add edit delete records

Comment: assertz and retract are the predicates you are looking for @MonkeBegin